# Unable to send a POST login request using Cypress

Tags: api, request, cypress, end-to-end

I am writing an end-to-end test for a website using Cypress and would like to make an API POST request to authenticate a user.

I have been able to make a request that sends back a 200 response code with an appropriate jwt.

Here is a code snippet of what the request looks like:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {

cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.website.com/api/login',
    body: {
        email: "xxx",
        password: "xxx"
    }
}).then((resp) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('jwt', resp.body.token)
    // console.log(resp.body.token)
    cy.log(resp)
})
cy.visit('/')
```

Here is an image of the Cypress test output:
[Cypress test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUufs.png)

Here is an image of the Chrome console, showing a successful response code:
[Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhBPi.png)

After reading the [Cypress command log](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests#Command-Log), I noticed that the white circle indicates the request was unable to reach the server (the request was stubbed). What are the possible reasons for this happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by 'white circle'? Can you try with this `cy.log(JSON.stringify(resp))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I have managed to resolve my issue. The request was working however, I was not setting the right data in local storage in order to authenticate. After using the Google Chrome Developer tools, I found that both the auth._token.local and auth.refresh_token.local needed to be set after the request. I have attached the code snippet below to help anyone who comes across a similar issue. Thanks.

```
cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login',
    body: {
        email: "email",
        password: "password",
    }
}).then((resp) => {
    localStorage.setItem('auth._token.local', 'Bearer ' + resp.body.token)
    localStorage.setItem('auth._refresh_token.local', false)
});
cy.visit('/');
```

Answer (score 1):

In this [section of the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Verifying-the-request-modification)

> cy.intercept() cannot be debugged using cy.request()! Cypress only intercepts requests made by your front-end application.

which means any `cy.request()` you issue in the test cannot be intercepted, and therefore cannot be stubbed.

I would say the white circle means the response was served from browser cache (just a guess).